# How to send base64 string as image in Node.js using nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, image, email, base64, nodemailer

I have nodejs get request which need to send the  base 64 string as image in the email which as shown below

```
router.post('/sendEmailNotification', function(req, res, next){
    var inlineBase64 = require('nodemailer-plugin-inline-base64');
//here i have big image    
let img ='/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBx'
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 587,
            secure: false,
    //       secure: true,
            secureConnection: false,// true for 465, false for other ports
            auth: {
                user: 'dhanalakshmi.07k@gmail.com',
                pass: '23'
            },
            tls:{
                rejectUnauthorized:false
            }
        });
    transporter.use('compile', inlineBase64({cidPrefix: 'somePrefix_'}));
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'dhanalakshmi.06k@gmail.com',
            to: 'dhanalakshmi.06k@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
            text: 'That was easy!',

            html: '&lt;img src=data:image/png;base64,'+img+'/>'
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                res.send(info.response);
            }
        });

    });
```

after the email send this should received as image but it  showing the entire tag with image string please say

```
html: '&lt;img src=data:image/png;base64,'+img+'/>' how should i send this to get the actual image
```

Comment: Isn't there problem with the `&lt;` at beginning (should be `<`)? I also think that it can be a problem for some clients that the HTML email body doesn't have this structure `<html><head></head><body><img/></body></html>`

btw You can also send it as an embeded image and reference it from the HTML email body https://nodemailer.com/message/embedded-images/

Comment: no that is not the issue

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this:

```
html: '<html><body><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA9QAAADmCAIAAAC77FroAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAAO..."></body></html>'
```